# Проблема с TabLayout, не вызывается метод onPause()

Tags: android, android-fragment, view, android-tablayout

У меня есть `ProductFragment` в котором находится `TabLayout` и `ViewPage`

Содержимое фрагмента(`fragment_product.xml`):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:ddIndicatorColor="@color/colorArrow"
    app:ddAnimatedIndicator="lineMove"
    app:ddIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

В `ProductFragment`, в методе `OnStart`, я добавляю элементы(3 фрагмента) к `ViewPage`

Собственно сам метод `OnStart`

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getActivity().setTitle(product.getName());

    aboutTabFragment = new  AboutTabFragment();
    optionsTabFragment = new OptionsTabFragment();
    reviewsTabFragment = new ReviewsTabFragment();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(aboutTabFragment,getString(R.string.about_product_text));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(optionsTabFragment,getString(R.string.optons_product_text));
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(reviewsTabFragment,getString(R.string.reviews_product_text));

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

В фрагментах `AboutTabFragment`, `OptionsTabFragment`, `ReviewsTabFragment` нет ничего особенного, пару текстовых полей и всё.

Теперь проблема: Когда в фрагменте `ProductFragment` вызываются методы завершения жизненного цикла фрагмента `onPause` -> `onStop` ..и т.д. до `onDetach` в вложенных фрагментах не вызывается даже `onPause` в следствии чего, при повторном открытии `ProductFragment` методы начала жизненного цикла,во вложенных фрагментах, не вызываются.

P.S. Пытался вызвать метод `onDestroy` у вложенных фрагментов из родительского `ProductFragment` всё равно не помогло.

Comment: А если viewPager наполнять фрагментами в onCrreate? Зачем вы испоьзуете onStart?

Comment: Перенес наполнение в onCreatedView, увы не помогло. А в методе onCreate ссылка на viewPager = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Провозился с этим часов 5 точно, проблема оказалась в строке инициализации ViewPageAdapter

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Заменил на

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```